# Trying to make an image with a hover effect a link

Tags: html, css

Are either of these valid to make a container with a hover effect become a link? I have six of these on my homepage, addition to a few text links a the top of the page?

I thought wrapping the whole div would work, then thought maybe I just wrap the hover state. Neither worked.

```
             <a href="/organdonor.html">

            <img src="/images/console/organdonor.jpg" />

            <div class="mask">
                <h2>Organdonor.gov</h2>
                <p>GOVERNMENT</p>
            </div>

           </a> 

        </div>





    <a href="/coach.html">
        <div id="console_coach" class="view">
            <img src="/images/console/coach.jpg" />
            <div class="mask">
                <h2>Coach</h2>
                <p>FASHION</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
```

[image]

Comment: Any other guesses as to why this isn't working? I don't get a mouseover effect either indicating a link, as well a not opening a link. (the finger pointer on a Mac)

Comment: Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/danbenner/pen/LWBvgM

Comment: It did work, but only responded when uploaded to a site. It didn't work on my local preview for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are both valid according to HTML5. However, please do notice older versions of HTML did not consider *non-inline* elements as valid child elements of an anchor tag.

> The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links). This example shows how this can be used to make an entire advertising block into a link:

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Comment: I have a hover effect on it. Does that mean it's interactive content?

Comment: Good question! But no, it means that an anchor element should never contain another button, another input, etc inside of it. The full list can be found in https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#interactive-content-0.